# wpf viewport3d from resource dictionary GetTemplateChild returns null

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I have added all my models as resource dictionaries as control template and i could load it using this code

```
 <Control Name="control" Width="507" Height="309" Template="{StaticResource SkeletonModel}"
```

now i want to edit that model in run time so iam trying to get the viewport3d that got loaded in the control element to edit it at runtime and i can't use triggers for it so i have to get reference to it then manipulate it from code behind here is the code i tried

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            Viewport3D v = this.GetTemplateChild("ModelView") as Viewport3D;

        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

v is always = null i also tried to change static resource to dynamic resource it didn't work i also tried couple of other ways like

```
Viewport3D v = control.Template.LoadContent() as Viewport3D;
            ModelVisual3D model;

            model = FindName("SkeletonHumanModel") as ModelVisual3D;
```

this does loads both the viewport and the model but when i edit either of them it does not get edited so i guess that loadcontent just loads a copy or another instance not the current instance used in the window 
here is the resource dictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                    mc:Ignorable="d"

    >
    <!--x:Class="Dynamic.ModelOperations"
                     x:ClassModifier="public"-->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SkeletonModel" >

        <Viewport3D Width="500" Height="500"  x:Name="ModelView"  ClipToBounds="True" >

            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera FieldOfView="35" FarPlaneDistance="110.57139405398024" LookDirection="0,0,-38.5951803220261" NearPlaneDistance="0.1" Position="-16.3927650451661,9.1631622056011,38.1892213715065" UpDirection="0,1,0"/>
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
            <ModelVisual3D x:Name="World">
                <ModelVisual3D x:Name="AmbientLightContainer">
                    <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                        <AmbientLight x:Name="AmbientLight" Color="#FF7F7F7F"/>
                    </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                </ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D x:Name="DirectionalLightContainer">
                    <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                        <DirectionalLight x:Name="DirectionalLight" Color="#FF3F3F3F" Direction="0,0,-1">
                            <DirectionalLight.Transform>
                                <TranslateTransform3D OffsetZ="3" OffsetX="0" OffsetY="0"/>
                            </DirectionalLight.Transform>
                        </DirectionalLight>
                    </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                </ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D x:Name="SkeletonHumanModel"   >.....
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To get a resource from ResourceDictionary, you should use FindResource() method. If your resource dictionary is merged in App resources, from MainWindow, you can get the resource like this,

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = this.FindResource("SkeletonModel") as Viewport3D;
}
```

Comment: but this will just get a copy not the current loaded model right ?